# How can a non-Chinese-speaking traveller use the free Wi-Fi in 7-Elevens in Taiwan?

Tags: budget, taiwan, wifi, chinese-language

In another of my questions here I asked if any of the convenience store chains in Taiwan offer free Wi-Fi.

[Well today I found out that 7-Eleven does.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/77201/140)
[image: ibon Wifi ad]

But the sign up / log in pages are totally in Chinese. There is no translation I can find, and the user interface is far from obvious. Google Translate doesn't seem to be much help.

The ad says you need your passport and visa but doesn't say you need a phone to receive a code by SMS.

Here is a screen grab of the relevant part of [their sign-up / log-in page](https://www.ibonwifi.com.tw/index2.aspx) if you are able to translate it or otherwise figure it out:
[image: Sign up / log in page]

Comment: It must be a hint! :)

Comment: trial and error?
What fields do you expect there to be? Maybe user name, email address and password? If its coming up *s its probably the password one. I guess the middle one is email address?  - No Chinese here either but I've managed to get wifi working in countries where I dont know the language before

Comment: I tried a few things. On the upper part of the UI the top line gives you a choice of three services or something, the second wants your mobile phone number, and the third wants your password or PIN. I think the checkbox is "remember me" and I don't know what the two "submit" butts are for. They are graphical so Google Translate doesn't work on them. I don't know what the lower bit of UI is for at all, though it seems to be some kind of search?

Comment: [I've now found an online guide on how to register.](https://blog.hellowings.com/blog/2016/01/22/7-eleven-and-familymart-wifi-sign-up-tutorial/) both for 7-Eleven and for FamilyMart. But there's two problems. **1)** The 7-Eleven UI has changed. There is nothing resembling the "register" button in this help. **2)** This help only covers getting a code sent to your phone via SMS, nothing about applying with your passport as indicated in 7-Eleven's own English blurb for the service )-:

Comment: This belongs on Puzzling SE, IMO.

Comment: I couldn't answer it unless I try it by myself, but if I were you I will tap on the button 帳號申請 to create an account. On the proceeding page you will be guided to type in your passport, I guess, though it would be written in Chinese.

Answer (score 2):

Well there's another way that will sometimes get you access to free Wi-Fi in 7-Elevens in Taiwan even without figuring out how to use these systems.

In Dulan village in Taitung I asked the server at the front counter to help me log in to the Wi-Fi since a local expat friend told me they set up his for him.

I passed her my tablet with the login screen as shown in my question. Her English was not good so I'm not sure exactly what she asked me.

But it turned out they have a Wi-Fi in this 7-Eleven with just a regular password login as well as the ibon signal and the usual paid signals. She just entered the password for that signal for me!

**So it's worth just asking the staff, they may sidestep the whole thing!** Might help if you're a regular, paying customer. Might help if you're an "interesting foreigner". Might not work in busy stores in cities or tourist traps.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2023, 7-Eleven convenience stores in Taiwan have revamped their ibon Wi-Fi and it is now a very simple and quick 1-click process to use!

No need to read Chinese, no need to enter a phone number or passport number. Just tap or click and start browsing.